# Are return statements required for stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

If you have a stored procedure that deletes record in a table, do you have to put a return statement and why?

I have always never put a return statement, but I just saw a snippet that has a return statement.

**Sample:**

```
DELETE 
FROM TableName
WHERE TableId = @Id

RETURN
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, an empty `return` statement is optional.  The only time it would be required is if you needed to return a value from the procedure, then you would need to either create a result set with a `select` statement or `return` a value.

In cases like yours the `return` statement is purely optional.

Answer (score 5):

I think you answered your own question:

> > I have always never put a return statement

A return statement is **not** required.

Answer (score 2):

No, Return statement is not at all compulsary.
if you need to get some value whether it is a datatable or any datatype then only you have to use return keyword.

Return can be used at the time of calling a stored procedure from another stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary. It just indicates that you have finished working on that particular stored procedure. Return statement is usually good in conditions

Answer (score 0):

I've always returned the number of records modified but it isn't required.