# can we have a stored procedure with output parameters and return statement?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Can a stored procedure have output parameters and return statement? If so can anybody give me a simple example.thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Stored procedure can return integer type only in a return statement and can have any number of out parameters. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921132/are-return-statements-required-for-stored-procedures/1921161#1921161) for references supporting this.

Simplest eg of stored procedure

**Return integer value from SP**

```
CREATE procedure [sys].[sp_name]
(
    @var1       bit = 0,
    @publisher  smallint                    
)
AS
BEGIN

    IF @var1<> 0
        RETURN (@publisher  )
 END
```

**Using Out Parameter**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetImmediateManager
   @employeeID INT,
   @managerID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT @managerID = ManagerID 
   FROM HumanResources.Employee 
   WHERE EmployeeID = @employeeID
END
```

You can use Transactions, Exception handling(try Catch), DDL and DML Queries, calling another stored procedure within one stored procedures and many more operations.

Please comments for more functionalities supported in stored procedure

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_name, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'var1'.


above error coming while executing.any code changes?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_name, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'var1'.

Comment: @Venkat: Here is the piece of code of system stored procedure. I made it little small to make it more clear. In previous code I forgot to use @ operator

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the standard RETURN statement that gives an integer then yes

If you mean a UDF RETURN , then no. But a stored proc can have a normal SELECT

Answer (score 1):

You are free to use both `OUTPUT` params and a single `RETURN` value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RaiseToPower (
      @IN  INT, 
      @OUT INT OUTPUT
   )
AS
   DECLARE @POWER INT 
   SET @POWER = 3
   SET @OUT = POWER(@IN, @POWER)
   RETURN @POWER
GO

/**/
DECLARE @POW INT, @RESULT INT

EXEC @POW = dbo.RaiseToPower 2, @RESULT OUTPUT 

SELECT 2, 'raised to', @POW, 'is', @RESULT

>> 2 raised to 3 is 8
```

Answer (score -1):

No. It is either a stored procedure or a scalar function.

A scalar function returns a value and takes 0 to n in parameters.

A stored procedure can take from 0 to n input parameters and can have 0 to n output parameters.

Comment: Eh? It's entirely possible to have both output parameters and a return value from a stored procedure. You can even have a result set too.